# Making 2 horizontal buttons fill the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

Here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Güncelle" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Doviz" >

    </ListView>

    **<Button
         android:layout_toLefttOf="@+id/Doviz"
        android:id="@+id/Altin"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Altın" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Doviz"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Döviz" />
</RelativeLayout>**
```

Ok the buttons whict i want to fill the parent with are Doviz and Altin others are irrelevant.

I tried making width for both of them fill_parent hoping they might get half - half didn't work.
I tried giving them width as "0dp" didnt work.

My question is  how i can make them(buttons) get the width %50-%50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Güncelle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnHolderLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Altin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Altın" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Doviz"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Döviz" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnHolderLL" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yeah this worked just as i wanted thank you for help :)

Answer (score 3):

wrap both buttons around LinearLayout and set their width to fill_parent as well as same layout weight

```
<LinearLayout layout_width="fill_parent" ... >
 <Button layout_width="fill_parent" layout_weight="1" ... />
 <Button layout_width="fill_parent" layout_weight="1" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Buttons will be assigned 50% of the width of the parent layout

Answer (score 0):

check this out  :)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGnc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Güncelle" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/linear"
         android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGnc">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Altin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Altın" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Doviz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Döviz" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code it will help you in every device


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Güncelle" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button

        android:id="@+id/Altin"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Altın" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Doviz"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGnc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Döviz" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain layout_weight in relative layout like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Altin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerView"
    android:text="Altın" />

<View 
   android:id="@+id/centerView"
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:visibility="invisible"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Doviz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerView"
    android:text="Döviz" />
```